# Getting RTSP stream with Opencv and python

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ffmpeg

I know this could be the 100th question of this kind, but I dug up google and everything, and I could not find anything working.
I need to get an `RTSP` stream with `opencv` in python, and I'm out of ideas. 
 Here's what I tried so far:

- Tried to stream with `ffserver` and `ffmpeg` but even when I got it working, I could see the stream only in the browser with very high latency, and not working in `opencv`
- Tried to stream directly to `udp` with `ffmpeg` but again, no luck
- Tried [this](https://gist.github.com/eruffaldi/1226191b0dd50737e74dafc0ec73caad#file-ffmpeg_opencv-py) script, but all I got was corrupted and unusable images.

Any ideas? I'm running on Mac OSX Sierra, I have compiled `OpenCV 3.2.0` with `ffmpeg` support and I'm using `Python 2.7`. 
My cam is a Sricam SP09 and my `RTSP` url is the following:

`rtsp://973704:888888@192.168.1.78:554/onvif1`

Comment: We used to make do with just `cap=cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://link_here")`. But if it wasn't good on `ffserver`, it seems like your stream doesn't work quite well.

Comment: I've read that `opencv` does not behave quite well with the `rtsp` protocol, hence the need to use `ffserver`. I'm convinced that I'm doing something wrong with `ffserver`, because often I cannot see the stream on my browser too :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You might be able to solve it with some additional codes.

import os

os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://[IP_CAM_ADDRESS]", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

Hope to be helpful to somebody.