# OpenCV VideoCapture: Nonmatching transport in server reply

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp

Im using python and opencv to open a rtsp url (from camera ip). And get this error:

```
    [rtsp @ 000002a9841927c0] Nonmatching transport in server reply
    warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
    warning: rtsp://admin:Abc12345@192.168.x.x:554/onvif1 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
```

I've already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51486322/11220956, but it's still not working.
The rtsp url work well when I use VLC to stream.

Here is some code

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:Abc12345@192.168.x.x:554/onvif1')
if capture.isOpened():
    while (True):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```